# Write a polynomial equation

Tags: functions, polynomials

Write a polynomial equation with the following characteristics. 
A quartic function with roots of -3, -1, and 4 (x=4 has a multiplicity of 2) and which passes through the point (5,16)

I know how to relate the roots to a polynomial equation, but I don't know how the point (5,16) is related to the function, so I cannot complete the equation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How does the general quartic with zeros $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ look?

Comment: ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e = 0; a,b,c,and d being coefficients and e being a constant.

Comment: I was thinking of a different representation. A product.

Comment: As in factored form? (x+a)(x+b)(x+c)? In this case (x+c) will be squared..

Comment: I think the idea is to write the equation in factored form and write it out. I had this so far: (x+3)(x+1)(x-4)(x-4), just not sure where the point (5, 16) fits in..

Comment: There's a constant factor that you can tweak, $c(x+3)(x+1)(x-4)^2$. Adjust $c$ so that if you plug in $x = 5$, the result is $16$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$$ f(x) = \alpha(x+3)(x+1)(x-4)^2 $$
Then solve $f(5) = 16$ for $\alpha$. Plug that $\alpha$ into $f(x)$ as given above, and you're done.

Here I have used the general form
$$f(x) = \alpha(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)(x-r_4)$$
where $\alpha$ is the coefficient of $x^4$, and $r_i$ are roots.

Answer (score 0):

with the ansatz
$f(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$ we have
$f(-3)=0$
$f(1)=0$
$f(4)=0$
$f'(4)=0$
and $f(5)=16$
you will get an equation system and you must solve this.

Comment: Alright, I'll try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well generally your equation will look like $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\delta)(x-\gamma)=y$ where $\alpha,\beta,\delta,\gamma$ are your roots. Multiplying the entire equation by a constant, say $k$ will not change your root values. Try creating your function and solving for $k$ using your point on the line.

I should state that $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\delta)(x-\gamma)=0$ is the same as $k(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\delta)(x-\gamma)=0$, since you can clearly divide both sides by k and get back the first equation. Thus the roots should remain intact.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So, would I solve my equation without changing anything, and then solve for k by substituting, say 5 in for x?

Comment: Essentially yes. Just create the equation, then solve $f(5)=16$ for the value $k$.

Answer (score 0):

As you already figured out, for your particular problem you can write a polynomial
with the required zeros like this, for suitable $a,b,c$:
$$f(x) = (x+a)(x+b)(x+c)^2.$$
And as has been noted, this polynomial also has the same roots:
$$g(x) = k(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)^2.$$

So write $f(x)$ in whatever format you need, and evaluate $n = f(5).$
If $n = 16,$ you would be done.
But if not, you at least want $g(5) = 16.$

Now you have $f(5)=n$ for a known value $n,$ and $g(5) = kf(5) = 16.$
This should be sufficient to find $k$ and to write $g(x)$ in the desired format.